# Creating an instance of axios in Vue not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using axios for AJAX in Vue. In the [article](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4) written by You, he mentioned that we can set `Vue.prototype.$http = axios` and  I can use `this.$http` in Vue instance. It works fine.

However, if I want to create an axios instance to `$http`, like

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://app.herokuapp.com/'
})
```

It does not work when I use `this.$http.get('/relativeURL')`. It seems that it cannot access the config I set. That is, it will not send request to `https://app.herokuapp.com/relativeURL`

In another way, if I set axios instance in any other object, such as `Vue.prototype.$axios = axios.create({config})`. It works successfully.

Could someone explain why this happen ??

Answer (score 7):

While defining it at Vue instance level might have its own merit, I don't like to pollute the global namespace. What my approach is, I have a `gateway` folder, where I have different files for axios instance, such as:

**backend-api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://YourAPiIp:9090/api/v1',
  timeout: 100000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

Now you can import it the place you want and use it:

```
import backendApi from '../../gateways/backend-api'
```

Answer (score 1):

You set

```
Vue.prototype.$https = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://app.herokuapp.com/'
})
```

And use

```
this.$http...
```

Typo in property name (https vs http).

Leave it as $http. Or simply don't even declare $http if it misleads you - use just `this.axios.get`...

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo.